# Android .AAB in GooglePlay Store does not load load languages with EnabledLanguageSplit

Tags: android, google-play, build.gradle, android-app-bundle

We had an AAB release in play store with the following `build.gradle` config

```
bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
```

Our testers found following issue:

1. Device languages only contains english
2. They downloaded the app from store (only english is bundled, as expected)
3. They added a new system language (german) and change the device language to german
4. They started the app again

Expected behaviour:
The app shows german language

Current behaviour:
The app shows english language

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/app-bundle-format#user_language_changes) prompts

> When a user switches their language in the device settings, Google Play may need to download and install some additional split APKs before the app can be displayed in the new language.

> Google Play tries to download the additional languages immediately after the switch. If the user device is offline, the download fails, or the resources are too large, Google Play attempts the download again in the background when the device conditions are more favourable.

However, this never happened to us, even if we waited a couple of days.

My questions are:

- Is my Expected behaviour wrong?
- When should this "google language reload" happen, how can i test, trigger or verify it?
- Is this working for you or did I miss some further implementations?